# Why is a graph Laplacian matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Why is a graph's Laplacian matrix positive semidefinite? Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation and a proof?

Comment: It's symmetric and diagonally dominant.

Comment: See also the [Gershgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

Comment: Two nice proofs that the Laplacian matrix of a graph is PSD: https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6334/lecture7.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $B$ is the incidence matrix of an orientation of $G$, then $L=BB^T$. So

$$ x^TLx = \|Bx\|^2 \ge 0$$

for all $x$.

The matrix has rows indexed by the vertices, columns by edges and the $ij$-entry is 1 if the $i$-th vertex is the head of the $j$-th edge, $-1$ if its the tail and 0 otherwise.